# while creating ORC partition from DataFrame : Error java.io.IOException: Unable to acquire 67108864 bytes of memory

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, partition, orc

`myDF.write.format("orc").partitionBy("creation_date").save("/user/xyz/data3")`

When Iam trying to create partitioned data file in ORC format based on "creation_date" column of myDF dataframe in HDFS directory /user/xyz/data3, Iam getting the following error: java.io.IOException: Unable to acquire 67108864 bytes of memory.

I have tried all the possible scenarios which are posted on internet related to this problem and none of them worked for me. Some of them which I tried are: `sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.tungsten.enabled", "false")`
`sqlContext.setConf("spark.buffer.pageSize", "16m")`

Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

This issue is appearing in Spark 1.5.1.

Error screen shot.[java.io.IOException: Unable to acquire 67108864 bytes of memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRALT.jpg)